# LCI calculations in brightway and access to CFs

Tags: brightway

I have imported ecoinvent 3.7.1 on a brightway project and i followed a few tutorials to understand brightway set up procedures and usage.

I want to use brightway to perform calculations on the inventory data of some processes (in particular i want to sum all emissions to air of CO2, CH4, N2O.

I tried with:

```
for exc in process.biosphere():
    for k,v in exc.items():
        print("\n",k,v)
```

But what i found to be in the bioshpere data is not the ecoinvent inventory, but the UPR. How do i access the LCI results?

**Edit:** i also tried to instantiate an lca and query the related biosphere object after performing lci() and lcia() but i always find the UPR data

```py
eidb = bw.Database('ecoinvent 3.7.1_cutoff_ecoSpold02') #seleziono il db 

process = eidb.search("diesel, burned in agricultural machinery")
method = ('IPCC 2013', 'climate change', 'GWP 100a')

lca = LCA({process[0]:1},method)
lca.lci()
lca.lcia()
lca.biosphere_dict
lca.biosphere_matrix
```

After this, i need to access the C.F. for such elements (the method i am interested in is IPCC 2013, GWP100a indicator). Is it possible to access the C.F.s for this method/substances in any way?

Answer (score 2):

you ask several things in the same question, but I will try to answer them.

lets take as an example the query you used. If I run

```
searchquery = eidb.search("diesel, burned in agricultural machinery")
```

I get two results. the market and the transforming activities, for the example I choose the transforming activity.

You can loop the biosphere exchanges of that activity and have a look to some of their attributes:

```
for exc in transf_act.biosphere():
   print(exc.input,exc.amount,exc.unit)
```

if you want to calculate the LCI (e.g. how much N2O will be emitted per kg of diesel burned considering all the life cycle:

```
lca = bw.LCA(demand={transf_act:1}) # you don't need a method unless you want LCIA results
lca.lci()
lca.inventory
```

the inventory is a sparse matrix with biosphere flows as rows and activities as columns, which with the common notation would be $B \cdot diag(s)$. It is not super straight forward to operate with it but you can ask a more specific question if you really need to dig into that matrix.

to get the CO2eq score of the LCA of burning diesel in an agricultural machinery

```
lca = bw.LCA(demand={transf_act:1},
   method=('IPCC 2013', 'climate change', 'GWP 100a'))
lca.lci()
lca.lcia()
lca.score
```

to have a look to the characterisation factors of the IPCC method:

```
cfs = bw.Method(('IPCC 2013', 'climate change', 'GWP 100a')).load()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was going to edit to write how i managed to access the CFS for the method. I am especially interested in working on the LCI matrix, i will look into the matrix to see if i can manage to get the aggregation i need ( i am looking to get the % content of CH4, N20 and CO2 contributing to the final score for the method)

Comment: I did look into the inventory matrix, and yes it is definetely not striaght forward hot to operate with it. How can i get more specific information on this?

Comment: ok, you need to look into the `characterized_inventory` matrix (which is the one with where all the emisisons are already in "CO2eq" basis. find the rows that correspond to the elemntary flows you are interested in. The sum of each row would be the contribution of a GHG. I keep forgetting how to operate with sparse matrices, so I don't have the answer on top of my head. I would look into the very detailed material developed by @MPa and CMutel here :  https://github.com/PoutineAndRosti/Brightway-Seminar-2017/blob/master/Day%201%20AM/2%20-%20BW%20structure%20and%20first%20LCAs.ipynb.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, installing the Activity Browser ( https://github.com/LCA-ActivityBrowser/activity-browser ) was the easieast way to understand what i was doing and get the results i was looking for!